# How to add a "sending/fetching" state when using async await?

Tags: javascript, forms, async-await, state

I am using async await to fetch a google form and add a new form submission to that form. I am using async await to handle the fetching, but I would like to add a state to a button that says, "Sending" while the fetching is happening in the background and then say, "Message sent" when the fetching is successful.

Here is my code so far, but I'm not sure where to put the "sending" state:

```js
 // submit form on button submit
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        // fetch google sheet script data & add submit form
        let res = await fetch(scriptURL, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: new FormData(form),
        })
        
        console.log('Success!', res)
        messagSent(e)

        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`)
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
})

 // Reset form fields
  const messagSent = (e) => {
    const button = document.getElementById('submit-button')
    form.reset()
    button.innerText = 'Message Sent'
    button.disabled = e
    button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed'
  }
```

Comment: Why not right after `e.preventDefault()`? Where have you tried to put this code before posting here, and why didn't it meet your requirements?

Comment: That worked! I just added `const button = document.getElementById('submit-button')` and `button.innerText = 'Message Sent'` directly after `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Just put it anywhere other than after the `await`. You can put it inside `fetchData` before the try block or as the first statement of the try block; or you can put it in the event handler before the `e.preventDefault()`, before the `fetchData()` call, or even after the `fetchData()` call.